# Firebase Cloud Message Push Notifications giving errors

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So basically I have tried to implement Push Notifications using Firebase cloud message module. Initially I wasnot able to recieve notifications but after reasearch about the difference in code for Oreo versions of androi Notifications are working fine when the app is in the foreground but gives the following error when the app is closed or is in the background:

[image]

So when I monitored the log cat carefully this what it is showing:

> Error while parsing timestamp in GCM event
>       java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
>           at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>           ...

My FirebaseMessageService class code is like this:

```
    public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

        private  String CHANNEL_ID = "personal_notifications";
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,"personal_notifications",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);


        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);


            String notification_title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String notification_message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

            String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();


                String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.chitchat_icon)
                                .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setContentText(notification_message);


                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(click_action);
                resultIntent.putExtra("user_id", from_user_id);


                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                this,
                                0,
                                resultIntent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        );

                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


                int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }

            mNotificationManager.notify(mNotificationId,mBuilder.build());
        } 
}
```

I don't know why my channel is null only when I try to send the notification in the background.

**Edit:**
When I am building the project on Linux Push Notifications appear in foreground and give above error in background but when I build it from windows I do not recieve any notification neither in background or foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the **failed to post notification on channel null** problem, you have to update your **firebase-messaging** version to latest or at least 15.0.2. Hope this will resolve the problem.

In addition to this you may add the below meta data in your **AndroidManifest** to double sure that it will work. Thanks

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

Comment: Which json file can you please elaborate?

Comment: Json object that you pass to Firebase API from your server / Postman. Please check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: If you want to use Firebase Console to send notification, then it will not work in **Background or Kill State** in android oreo and onwards.

Comment: I have deployed a js function to send the pay load: `const payload = {
     notification: {
      title: "Friend Request",
      body: `${userName} has sent you request`,
      icon: "default",
      click_action : "com.example.chitchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"
     }, 
     data : {
      from_user_id : from_user_id
     }
    };`

Comment: Ok, If you follow this process then you have to add intent filter of activity that you want to launch when click notification from system tray. <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.example.chitchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: What is your **firebase-messaging** version?

Comment: My version is 10.2.0

Comment: Update it to latest or at least 15.0.2 and try

Comment: Thanks I updated it to 11.4.0 and It got Resolved please Include this in your answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I will also rebuild it with windows and check if it works there also, hopefully

Comment: I want to ask one more thing is when I recieved notification when app is in foreground or background the pendingIntent opens exactly the correct activity for me ... but when app is closed and I try to click the notification the app doesn't gets to right intent and closes without showing anything...

Comment: Where you put the intent filter means which activity? that activity will launch and you have to parse the data for further process from bundle of that activity's **onCreate**.

Comment: `<activity android:name=".ProfileActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.chitchat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200549/discussion-between-rehan-and-md-asaduzzaman).